# How to log the content of TCP connection proxied through HAProxy

Tags: docker, tcp, haproxy, netcat

In the logs from HAProxy I would like to log the content of the TCP connection.

So if a TCP connection sends the word "hello" over TCP through my HAProxy I would like the word "hello" to show up in the logs.

My haproxy-server is running Ubuntu Server 18.04 and has Docker 19.03.12 installed. I'm running the [official haproxy docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy) version 2.7.3.

I'm starting the container with docker-compose version 1.27.1 and this is the compose file:

```yaml
services:
  ftt_tcp_proxy_dev:
    container_name: ftt_tcp_proxy_dev
    image: haproxy:2.7.3
    ports:
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - /home/user1/git/ftt_tcp_proxy/dev/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
```

My haproxy configuration looks like this:

```
global
    log stdout format raw daemon

defaults
    mode tcp
    log global
    log-format "[%t] Connection on port %fp from ip %ci forwarded to %si:%sp with data x"
    timeout client 60s
    timeout client-fin 60s
    timeout connect 60s
    timeout server 60s
    timeout server-fin 60s
    timeout tunnel 60s

frontend server1
    bind :50000
    default_backend server2

backend server2
    server server2 10.10.150.82:50000
```

On server2 (Ubuntu Server 18.04) I run this command to listen on port 50000: `nc -nvlkp 50000`

From server1 (Ubuntu Server 18.04) I run this command to connect to server2 through HAproxy: `nc haproxy01 50000`

`haproxy01` is a DNS record that resolves to the IP-address of the server running HAProxy docker container.

The connection is initiated and logged from HAProxy container:

```
[03/Apr/2023:13:29:57.751] Connection on port 50000 from ip 10.10.150.81 forwarded to 10.10.150.82:50000 with data x
```

From server1 I can in netcat write the word "hello"

```
user1@server1:~$ nc haproxy01 50000
hello
```

and it shows up in server2

```
user2@server2:~$ nc -nvlkp 50000
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 50000)
Connection from 10.10.150.42 34878 received!
hello
```

But as the title explains I want the word "hello" to also show up in my HAProxy log instead of symbol x at the end. Obviously it wont work with the above configuration since I neither capture it nor log it. I just have it as an example to show my starting point.

I have tried adding `tcp-request inspect-delay 5s` and `tcp-request content capture req.payload(0,100) len 100` in frontend section and `%[capture.req.hdr(0)]` in log-format so the configuration looks like this:

```
global
    log stdout format raw daemon

defaults
    mode tcp
    log global
    log-format "[%t] Connection on port %fp from ip %ci forwarded to %si:%sp with data %[capture.req.hdr(0)]"
    timeout client 60s
    timeout client-fin 60s
    timeout connect 60s
    timeout server 60s
    timeout server-fin 60s
    timeout tunnel 60s

frontend server1
    bind :50000
    default_backend server2
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content capture req.payload(0,100) len 100

backend server2
    server server2 10.10.150.82:50000
```

But when I repeat the experiment above only a dash is logged

```
[03/Apr/2023:13:48:08.991] Connection on port 50000 from ip 10.10.150.81 forwarded to 10.10.150.82:50000 with data -
```

So what can I do to log the content of the connection?

**Update 1**

I have successfully logged the word "hello" now by changing to this line in haproxy configuration:

`tcp-request content capture req.payload(0,5) len 5`

However, if I send a word shorter than 5 characters only a dash is logged. If I send a word longer than 5 characters only the first 5 characters are logged.

How can I log this without knowing the length of the content?

**Update 2**

I have given up. I now use tcpdump to log the content. It's possible with this command:

`sudo tcpdump -i any -nn -A port 50000`